# Angular CLI can't find modules from locally installed library

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I create an angular library: `@my_library/sdk` and also created a samples project to test it. The problem is, while installing the library on my samples project angular's build complains it can't find the module:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve '@my_library/sdk' in
>   '/Users/eestein/Documents/dev/my_library/sdk-front/samples/src/app'
>   ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve '@my_library/sdk' in
>   '/Users/eestein/Documents/dev/my_library/sdk-front/samples/src/app'

If I open both offending files (`app.component.ts` and `app.module.ts`) in VSCode no error is shown. It looks like VSCode can find it, but Angular CLI can't. The package is also there at node_modules' folder.

This is what I have in my `package.json` of the samples project:

```
"@my_library/sdk": "file:///Users/eestein/Documents/dev/my_library/sdk-front/library/my_library-sdk-1.0.0-alpha.2.tgz"
```

This is my folder structure:

```
- library
   - library's code
   - *.tgz file
- samples
    - samples' code
    - package.json referencing the tgz file
```

I've opened an issue on angular's cli GitHub page, but it's been 8 days and no replies, so I'm trying SO now...

This is the link for the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11054

#### Setup

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 7.7.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be? The problem is local, if I publish the library to my private npm repo and install it from there, it works.

Thanks.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) it looks like it uses a relative path. Also, it should point at the directory, not a compressed file I believe.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment hey, thanks, but I tried both ways. And actually it was npm install --save that created that entry. And if I look into the node_modules' folder, the library is correctly placed there.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I just tried again to be sure, same thing :/

Comment: Sorry, I've never done this before. To do what you're describing, I've always used [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Comment: @peinearydevelopment np, thanks. I've always done that as well, but it's being discourage so I'm trying this approach now.

Comment: Wondering if you got anywhere with this.  I have seen questions around the internet but no answers.  Seems possibly something to do with @namespace notation, but also I notice that the error indicates that it is trying to find the module in the dist folder, but `ng build --prod` deletes the contents of the dist folder so it cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even after you install the .tgz file that angular-cli still looks for the module in the `paths` section of `tsconfig.json`, which is usually `dist/@namespace/lib`.

The problem is that `ng build --prod` deletes the contents of the dist folder before it compiles and so when it tries to actually build the app the the modules no longer exist.  I got around this by specifying the output of the build command so that the app goes to a different folder.

`ng build -prod --output-path=production`

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't my case though, all the proper files were present at the folder and I was referencing the packaged tgz (as explained in my question), and that file was loaded with the corrected files. I gave on trying to have it working few days after I opened the question here and moved to angular 6. It's working fine now!

Comment: `ng build --prod --output-path=production` is correct as u forgot one '-' before prod. But it is not working ...still same error